# How to display a list in a column of a ListView (WPF and C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, observablecollection

I have a class which is binded to a `ListView`

```
class Estudante
{
    public string primeironome { get; set; }
    public string segundonome { get; set; }
    public int[] notas { get; set; }
}
```

*MainWindow*:

```
ObservableCollection<Estudante> arrList = new ObservableCollection<Estudante>();
ListaAlunos.ItemsSource = arrList;
```

*XAML*:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding primeironome}"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding segundonome}"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding notas}"
```

But when I add any data to the collection, for instance:

```
arrList.Add(
            new Estudante
            {
                primeironome = "Svetlana",
                segundonome = "Omelchenko",
                notas = new int[] { 98, 92, 81, 60 }
            });
```

The result on the `ListView` is:

```
C1        C2         C3
Svetlana  Omelchenko Int32[] Array
```

And I would like it to be:

```
 C1        C2         C3
 Svetlana  Omelchenko 98, 92, 81, 60
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `string` property, for example

```
class Estudante
{
    public string primeironome { get; set; }
    public string segundonome { get; set; }
    public int[] notas { get; set; }
    public string StringNotas
    {
       get 
         {
            return string.Join(",", notas);
         }
   }
}
```

And bind to `StringNotas`

**Xaml**

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding primeironome}"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding segundonome}"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StringNotas}"
```

You will still create your data the same way

```
arrList.Add(
            new Estudante
            {
                primeironome = "Svetlana",
                segundonome = "Omelchenko",
                notas = new int[] { 98, 92, 81, 60 }
            });
```

And you will bind it the same way in `MainWindow`

```
ObservableCollection<Estudante> arrList = new ObservableCollection<Estudante>();
ListaAlunos.ItemsSource = arrList;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! It's worked brilliantly!

Comment: Sure, np, glad I could help :)